# Is it possible to export an ARM template for an azure function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-resource-manager

I need to export an azure ARM template for my azure function but cannot see any options in the portal, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Navigate to the resource group blade and pick "Automation Options", that would export the whole resource group.

Alternative way would be to use https://resources.azure.com and navigate to the resource in question and just copy\paste it